# Delete comments in review queues

Tags: feature-request, comments, review-queues

I was reviewing the Close queue when I saw one of my comments. (Please tag your DBMS, version included). I was about to delete it when I realized that it is not allowed while you are in reviewing mode.

Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?

I think it is a good place to remove your own comments, in fact I think they should appear remarked, bold font or a different colour.